# CodeIgniter - URL solution

Tags: php, url, codeigniter

I'm writing project in CI and I have winamp plugin that pass values to CI thru URL (e.g. http://localhost/class/method/value1/value2/value3/... )
I have to pass 7 values but last 3 of them sometimes will be empty (e.g. http://localhost/class/method/value1/value2/value3/value4///value7 ) but that way value7 in CI assign as value5, and that's not what I want.

My question :
Is there solution without adding extra symbol in winamp plugin like x:value7 and then removing x: and get only value itself.

Comment: You can still use regular query strings. If you're calling it from a Winamp plugin, it'd be better to use keys and values than making sure your arguments are always in order, anyways.

Comment: Is there way to enable query strings JUST for one or more controllers ?

Comment: yes...just rebuild the `$_GET` array by doing this: `parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);`. Just be sure to run it through the XSS filter if you plan on putting any of that info back out to the user.

Comment: Found even better solution: `http://localhost/controller/method/?field=value&field=value`

then in controller

`$field = $this->input->get('field');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of the values is empty mark it as empty, null, or 0 based on that this value represent:

`localhost/class/method/value1/value2/empty/value4/empty/value6/value7`

make sure that method will react correctly on "empty"

Comment: For those who want to know how i fix it:
`if (data.IsEmpty()) data = "%5F";`

%5F is actually _ and in CodeIgniter

`if($this->data == '_') $this->data = NULL;`